# Writing query in android?

Tags: database, sqlite, distinct, sql-like

Below is my query with which I want to do two things. First is there should not be any duplication in database. If any entry need to inserted with same name in database. It should not be inserted as entry as database. It should be just counted as integer number, it try to be inserted.H ere is my basic create query to create table and columns in it. Actually I don't know how to write query in this manner that why I am asking how to use here distinct or like keywords:

```
db.execSQL("create table " + OUTGOING_TABLE + " (" + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + NAME + " text, " + NUMBER + " text, " + DATE + " text, " + DURATION + "text);");
```

Comment: how can i use distinct and like in this format

Answer (score 0):

To make a column unique in a table, you can mark it as such:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Name text UNIQUE,
Number Integer);
```

However, unlike other DBMS's, SQLite can't resolve a conflict with an action (other than Rollback, Abort, Fail, Ignore, and Replace). You'll need to do that by hand. One approach is to check for your NAME value, if it exists, increment NUMBER, if not, insert. It's a 3 line function.